# Possibility of using self-referential foreign key to create hierarchical comments

Tags: postgresql, performance, table, alter-table

I am an accidental DBA and have a question regarding the table structure of a website I maintain (postgresql 9.6 backend).

Imagine a typical content website (let's call it 'Links'), where users post internet links and descriptions, and others leave comments under the posted content.

Currently all comments have a `flat` hierarchy. The comments table is simply:

```
                                      Table "public.links_publicreply"
     Column      |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_publicreply_id_seq'::regclass)
 submitted_by_id | integer                  | not null
 comment_for_id  | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 description     | text                     | not null

Indexes:
    "links_publicreply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_publicreply_comment_form_id" btree (comment_form_id)
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id" btree (submitted_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_publicreply_comment_form_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (comment_for_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitted_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_link" CONSTRAINT "latest_reply_id_refs_id_94fc0824" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

My intention is to migrate it to a 'reddit-like' hierarchical comments.

No DB expert here, but in my mind, I feel I should add two more rows to this flat table:

1) one a self-referential foreign key (let's call it `reply_to_id`),

2) the other being what depth of hierarchy the comment belongs to (e.g. reply to the outer most comment could have a depth of `1`, a reply to this reply could have a depth of `2`, so on).

```
                                     Table "public.links_publicreply"
     Column      |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_publicreply_id_seq'::regclass)
 reply_to_id     | integer                  |
 depth           | integer                  |
 submitted_by_id | integer                  | not null
 comment_for_id  | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 description     | text                     | not null

Indexes:
    "links_publicreply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_publicreply_reply_to_id" btree (reply_to_id)
    "links_publicreply_comment_form_id" btree (comment_form_id)
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id" btree (submitted_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_publicreply_reply_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (reply_to_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_publicreply_comment_form_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (comment_for_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitted_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_link" CONSTRAINT "latest_reply_id_refs_id_94fc0824" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Given this structure, I feel:

1) I can easily get all replies pointing to any comment, e.g. `Select * from links_publicreply where reply_to_id=id`. I'm fine with showing just 1 level of depth at a time, so no need to involve depth in this query.

2) I can always retrieve depth data along with the reply data, using it to visually indent the replies at the correct level of depth (as per reddit's practice).

Those are my two major use-cases at this point.

I'm running this by industry experts because I need clarity on whether a migration like this - which seemingly looks simple enough - comes with any potential pitfalls?

For example,

1) are self-referential foreign keys used in a scenario like this the right way to do it?

2) would row-deletion cause any unintended consequences? I.e. when a comment is deleted, are all replies to that comment deleted too as per my scheme?

Overall, how would you guys tackle a requirement like this? Along similar lines?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the noob question (if it is).

**Other notes:**

The question is a simplified scenario of a mid-sized, live project. The table I'm referring to has ~120M rows and growing (so `performance` is a huge point of consideration as well). I'm thinking when I apply `alter table`, I won't impose defaults so that the query runs fairly quickly.

Comment: This is a standard "adjacency model" which can easily be retrieved using a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) - I am not sure what exactly your question is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for that. I have rudimentary experiences with DBA, so I thought I'd specifically ask whether the changes I have in mind will fit my requirements. Do you think the changes I suggested to my table sound fine? And yes I do understand how to run `with` queries (although haven't extensively used them).